# error 1052 im trying to join tables using inner join however i keep getting this message

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Im looking to join two tables together using inner join but i keep getting this error saying that 'column 'isbn' in field list is ambiguous'. Ive seen a few questions about this but none of them solved my problem.

```
SELECT isbn, title
FROM book 
INNER JOIN copy ON book.isbn = copy.isbn
    WHERE duration = '7';
```

Comment: `duration` and `title` are columns from which table(s)

Answer (score 3):

I can see you have this column `isbn` in both `copy` and `book` table.
So you have to choose which of this `isbn` columns is selected. so you should have

```
SELECT book.isbn , title
FROM ....
```

Or

```
SELECT copy.isbn , title
FROM ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a column that is present on both tables, so SQL can't distinguish which one to select. You have to specify it like this:

```
SELECT book.isbn, title
FROM book 
INNER JOIN copy ON book.isbn = copy.isbn
    WHERE duration = '7';
```

or

```
SELECT copy.isbn, title
FROM book 
INNER JOIN copy ON book.isbn = copy.isbn
    WHERE duration = '7';
```